# Finding information about fields in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a node type with multiple file attachments and would like a node view to show the latest file attached to the node.

In Views, I have options to sort by node:updated or revision:vid, but of course they don't tell me which file was added last. Is there a way to sort by the updated time *of a field*?

And, more generally, is there a way to find information about changes to *parts* of a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no revision records for individual CCK fields that I've ever heard of. I think I saw a blog entry about someone thinking of writing a module for it.

Here's how you get the file upload date into a View:

1. Create a *Relationship* with the particular FileField you are interested in.
2. In *Fields* there will now be a File category. It includes `File Upload Date`.
3. In *Sort criteria* there is also a `File Upload Date`.

If you also restrict your View to a single node, that should do it.